# Problemas para correr programas de python en VS code

Tags: python, vscode

Instalé la nueva versión de Python (versión 3.9) y tengo instalado Visual Studio Code, al querer correr un programa me dice lo siguiente:

```
No se encontr¾ Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store ni
o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuraci¾  n > Administrar los alias de ejecuci¾n de aplicacUsiones.
```

Ya lo hice pero no me corre nada. Instalé y desinstalé repetidas veces Python pero sigue sin funcionar.
Tengo instalada la extensión de Python en vs code.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Nota: ni siquiera un `Hola mundo` me deja correr.

Comment: Como mencione, tengo instalada la extensión de python. Pero ya se soluciono, al momento de instalar python no lo agregaba al path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica que tengas instalado Python y su PATH en registrado en las variables de entorno del sistema, porque si no, no podrás ejecutar nada.

Más info acá:

https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: Si, se soluciono,gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me di cuenta que en mi variable de usuario ComSpec la ruta \WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe terminaba con el signo ";" que según lo que investigue evita que la ruta se leida. borre la completamente ComSpec y también la ruta, y cree una nueva variable con la misma ruta pero con \WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe pero sin ";" al finalizar